# AFNetworking Asynchronous Data Fetching

Tags: objective-c, ios, asynchronous, objective-c-blocks, afnetworking

I'm using the AFNetworking library to pull a JSON feed from a server to populate a `UIPickerView`, but I'm having a little trouble wrapping my head around the asynchronous way of doing things. The `@property` `classChoices` is an `NSArray` that's being used to populate the `UIPickerView`, so that the web call is only performed once. However, since the block isn't finished by the time the instance variable is returned, the getter returns nil, and it eventually causes my program to crash later on. Any help in fixing this would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if you need any additional information.

**PickerViewController.m classChoices Getter**

```
- (NSArray *)classChoices {
    if (!_classChoices) {
        // self.brain here refers to code for the SignUpPickerBrain below
        [self.brain classChoicesForSignUpWithBlock:^(NSArray *classChoices) {
            _classChoices = classChoices;
        }];
    }
    return _classChoices;
}
```

**SignUpPickerBrain.m**

```
- (NSArray *)classChoicesForSignUpWithBlock:(void (^)(NSArray *classChoices))block {
    [[UloopAPIClient sharedClient] getPath:@"mobClass.php" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseJSON) {
        NSLog(responseJSON);
        if (block) {
            block(responseJSON);
        }
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

        if (block) {
            block(nil);
        }
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a method like the following in your PickerViewController which returns the array once it has been downloaded. Once the callback has been returned, you can then continue on with your code:

```
- (void)classChoices:(void (^) (NSArray * classChoices)) _callback {
    if (!self.classChoices) {
        // self.brain here refers to code for the SignUpPickerBrain below
        [self.brain classChoicesForSignUpWithBlock:^(NSArray *classChoices) {
            _callback(classChoices);
        }];
    }
}

// call the method

- (void) viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self classChoices:^(NSArray * updatedChoices) {

        self.classChoices = updatedChoices;

        [self.pickerView reloadAllComponents];

    }];

}
```

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear before, but `classChoices` is a `@property`; the code above is for overriding its getter. In addition, this is already a callback `SignUpPickerBrain`. Putting a callback inside a callback seems a little overly complex, right? What exactly are you saying would be done inside `_callback`?

Comment: Putting a callback inside a callback is fine and isn't particularly complex. There is no need to override the getter, just have `classChoices` as a standard NSMutableArray, and then call -classChoices (with the callback - my code posted above) when you need to update the array. The updating of the array would occur inside of the _callback. I'll updated the answer to include code for this.

Comment: I've edited your code to make it agree with the compiler, but the code still does not work. The program still crashes with the error: `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16)`.

Comment: You need to initialise classChoices before you add to the array.

Comment: Sorry, apparently I forgot to edit a piece of your code to fit what I'm doing. As you can see, `classChoices` (which is an `NSArray` by the way, not an `NSMutableArray` is getting initialized), but the crash persists.

Comment: What are the properties (nonatomic, assign/retain/readonly...) you are using to declare the property?

Comment: `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *classChoices;`

Comment: I actually realized that I still needed to make the `classChoicesForSignUpWithBlock:` method return void in order for it to work. It now works successfully. However, it seems like bad UI to just have a blank `UIPickerView` until the values show up (which could take a while depending on the data connection). What is the best practice in this case for making the user wait? Something like blocking the UI with the `SVProgressHUD` library?

Comment: Sounds like a perfect idea. I tend to use MBProgressHUD for HUDs containing an activity indicator and SVProgressHUD for alerts. Up to you.

Comment: One last question on this. If there is a good data connection, it seems almost like bad UI to have the progress HUD at all because it appears and then quickly disappears since the data loads quickly. What are the best practices regarding this?

Comment: Could just set the network activity indicator to run in the status bar, I can't say that I have thought about that before!